# button at end of <OL> to enter a new <LI> that contains datalist/input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, input, addition

I have created the following code for a list that contains two input fields per line : a space to enter a product and a space to enter the quantity.
Both have some restrictions and they need to be maintained. Especially the datalist code needs to be copied into the new list line.
At the end of the OL I would like to put a button that adds a new LI with the same properties as the original one, but I don't seem to find any solution.

would any of you guys know a way to solve this?
I have been looking for a while now but I am not able to come up with a solution.

```
<ol id=orderform>
    <li>
        <input type=text3 required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" placeholder="Select or type SKU or description" name="selectsku" id="selectsku" list="skulist" />
            <datalist id="skulist">
            </datalist>
        <input type=number required pattern="[0-9\s]+" placeholder=quantity  />
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: You have JavaScript and jQuery tags...but no JS/jQ posted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery. Clone the last element and append the clone after the last li. Something like this:

```js
$(function() { 

var mycounter=1;


$("#hi").click(function(){

$("#original").clone().prop('id', 'clone'+mycounter ).appendTo("#orderform")

mycounter++
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id=orderform>
    <li id="original">
        <input type=text3 required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" placeholder="Select or type SKU or description" name="selectsku" id="selectsku" list="skulist" />
            <datalist id="skulist">
            </datalist>
        <input type=number required pattern="[0-9\s]+" placeholder=quantity  />
    </li>
</ol>

<span id='hi'>hi</span>
```

Comment: hi @Hans Dash, any idea how such a code would look like? I have the following code, but the datalist is not working..

<input type="button" value="Add line" onclick="new_element()" /> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>  
<script>function new_element(){  
$("#header ol").append('<li><input type=text3 required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" placeholder="Select or type SKU or description" name="selectsku" id="selectsku" list="skulist" /><datalist id="skulist"></datalist><input type=number required pattern="[0-9\s]+" placeholder=quantity  />');  
} </script>

Comment: I added an example to my answer

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks a lot!
It seems to be working now.
One little thing though: between the bottom of the list (stops at line 30) and the button that is now working, there appears now:

1. 

-it's as if it opens another <ol> with one <il>.

Comment: Hi Koen, I dont understand. Between the ol and the span, there seems to be a number 1? when you run the code snippet? Which browser are you using?